# Can Ajax update a dynamic navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using a PHP function to determine what links are being displayed:

```
<?php
  //amend toplinks if logged in
  if($general->loggedIn()){ ?>
    <nav class = "memberHeaderArea">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="userProfile.php?username=<?php echo $user['username'];?>">Profile<span class="user icon"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="userLogout.php">Log out<span class="lock icon"> </span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  <?php
    //toplinks for when not logged in
  }else{ ?>
```

I've just changed the structure of my login to use Ajax and it works perfectly with the exception of the nav. It still shows login / register until a page refresh is called. Obviously the reason for using Ajax was to avoid the page refresh, but is there a way I can update these links within the success function?

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#statusLogin").hide();
  if(data.success == true){
    $('#loginContent').slideToggle();
  }else{
    // alert("data.message... " + data.message);//undefined
    $("#error").show().html(data.message);
  }
```

From what I've found, it looks like I may need to assign the nav's id and then use Ajax / jQuery to target that. But I'm not sure how. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be there until the ajax call returns. You could set the default state in php or you can make the `"checklogin"` call in the `$(document).ready(function(){ ...script here... }` block, so it will check it right after the page loads. You can even hide the entire area until the call returns...

Comment: @BalintBako I was just trying a .hide() as I'm pretty new to jQuery but I've used that for soemthing else. They seem to be overlapping though so not right just yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is so I drafted a sample (added as an answer)

Comment: Answer by Barmar here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771396/why-wont-my-div-reveal-itself-after-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic (and dummy) stuff for checking login status with AJAX after page loading. Probably you want more serious check then `if(true)` and an `echo` call, but it will be something like this :) Check the fiddle below, so you can see the html and the css too...

```
$.getJSON('/echo/json/').done(function (data) {
    console.log("Call returned");
    if (true){
        //successful login
        $('#loggedin').slideToggle();
    }else {
        //unsuccessful login
        $('#login').slideToggle();
    }
}).fail(function (data) {
    console.log("Call failed");
    $('#login,#error').slideToggle();
}).always(function (data) {
    console.log("Always running");    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnjcW/1/)

Comment: Hi, The problem that I'm having is that I always need one of the divs to show.  The ajax function is only called when a user clicks on submit after selecting login from the menu.  I can either get them both to hide, both to display (and not log in) or a combination that seems to fail.

Comment: The sample I wrote is probably what you need: you should check right after the page load if the user is logged in or not. It will always display one of the divs, with a little modification you can make on of these visible by default. You should consider a new _loading_ div, which would be displayed until you know if he was logged in or not.

Comment: I've modified it somewhat and now it works fine...until I click on another link.  The header is then refreshed and the links revert to login when logged in.

Comment: GAH! What am I doing wrong?! -.-  I've left in my original php if else in the header, this solves the problem for every page refresh etc.  I simply cannot make the loggedIn div appear when a user first logs in.  I can make the loggedOut one disappear but not the other.  I can't have display:none in the css as I need them to always be present in the header.

Comment: You could share the rendered html (not the php) + the current JS