# Why won't my div reveal itself after Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Newbie to Ajax/jQuery.  Everything I've tried so far fails.  I've a dynamic header for displaying links if logged in and if not logged in.

Using a simple php if else to display links.

Login drops down, on submit jQuery/Ajax function called.  Upon success I want the LoggedOut to hide which it does.  But the LoggedIn refuses to show itself.

I can't use display: none in css as this header and links should always be present.

Please help me so I can stop frowning and scratching head :)  Many thanks.

```
success: function(data) {

        $("#statusLogin").hide();

        if(data.success == true){

            $('#loggedIn').show();  //GAAAAAAAAAAAH!!!!!
            $('#loginContent').slideToggle();
            $('#loggedOut').hide();

        }else{
           // alert("data.message... " + data.message);//undefined
            $("#error").show().html(data.message);
        }

    },
```

EDIT:  Bulk of HTML

```
    <?php if($general->loggedIn()){ ?>

<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id="loggedIn">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="userProfile.php?username=<?php echo $user['username'];?>">Profile<span class="user icon"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="userLogout.php">Log out<span class="lock icon"> </span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<?php
     //toplinks for when not logged in
 }else{ ?>

<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id ="loggedOut">
    <ul>
        <li id="login">
            <a id="loginTrigger" href="#">Login<span class="unlock icon"></span></a>

            <div id="loginContent">

                <form method="post" action="" id="ourLoginFormID_JS">
                    <div id="error"></div>
                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" autocomplete="off" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['username']); ?>"  />
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="required"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label> &nbsp; </label>
                        <input type="submit" name="loginButton" id="loginButton" value="Login!" onclick="validLogin(); return false;"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="statusLogin"></div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="userRegister.php">Register<span class="adduser icon"></span></a>
        </li>


    </ul>
</nav>

 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Check for typos, and remember that it's case-sensitive.

Comment: What is the server's response?

Comment: @Barmar, no errors that I can see.  no typos. I've checked and then checked again

Comment: @YotamOmer server returns true for login.  I am logged in.  Should the above be working then?

Comment: try: `if(data.success == "true"){`

Comment: @Cherniv if it's hiding `#loggedOut`, he must be getting into that branch of the `if`.

Comment: @Barmar you know , everything is possible when you start to work with something new

Comment: @SteveGreen please paste the full response json. You can only use `data.message` and `data.success` if your response looks like {"success":"true","message":"my message"}

Comment: remember, `true` not always equals to `"true"`

Comment: @Cherniv No, some things are not possible. If he's testing correctly, it will execute all the then-statements. If he's testing incorrectly, it will skip them all and go to the else block.

Comment: @YotamOmer Response: {"success":true}

Comment: Does your div have id="loggedIn" or id="#loggedIn"? Common mistake that I do often ;)

Comment: Please post the relevant section of the HTML.

Comment: @contradictioned - You had me hoping then :) 
<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id="loggedIn">

Comment: @Barmar edited question to show HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
<?php if($general->loggedIn()){ ?>

<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id="loggedIn">
```

The user isn't logged in when the page is initially sent, so there's no `loggedIn` element in the DOM. When you login via AJAX, that doesn't change what's in the DOM. So there's nothing to show.

You should send this HTML unconditionally, and just use CSS and JS to hide and show it.

To get the initial state into jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
    var loggedIn = <?php echo json_encode($general->loggedIn()); ?>;
    $("#loggedIn").toggle(loggedIn);
    $("#loggedOut").toggle(!loggedIn);
});
```

Another way you can do it is like this:

```
<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id="loggedIn" <?php if (!$general->loggedIn()) echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?> >

...

<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id="loggedOut" <?php if ($general->loggedIn()) echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?> >
```

Comment: of course. -.- Can I use jquery script within php tags to detect if logged in and to show as need be?

Comment: No. PHP runs on the server when it's composing the page, jQuery runs on the client after it has received the page.

Comment: I knew as much but was hoping for some magic.  I need to use that php function on pretty much every page.  Would a workaround be to dulicate the nav, different ID, hide it and use the jquery to display that?  It's ugly but it might work

Comment: You can't put jQuery inside PHP, but you can do the opposite. I just edited the answer to show the "magic".

Comment: You're f**king beautiful!

Comment: Could you briefly explain why it needs encoding?  Am I right in thinking it turns the loggedIn result into a JSON array which then returns {true : false}?

Comment: `json_encode()` is just a way to ensure that a PHP value is properly formatted as a Javascript literal. It's just a true/false value, but if you `echo false` it echoes a blank, not the word `false`.

Comment: ah, that makes more sense, thanks!  I'd prefer to use the php within the js to avoid inline style etc.  This is going to be so useful for future purposes.  Can I vote again? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your initial page load doesn't include the `loggedIn` elements. You've got server-side code:

```
    <?php if($general->loggedIn()){ ?>
```

...that doesn't send those fields in the first place. Then you use an Ajax call to do the login, and that doesn't load any new content into the page, so then your jQuery `$('#loggedIn')` doesn't find the element because it doesn't exist. (You can confirm this by clicking your browser's "View Page Source" option (or equivalent) - you won't see that element).

You can fix this by either sending all of the HTML up front and then show or hide it as appropriate, and set the user name to display via jQuery/JS too, or by changing your Ajax to return the relevant HTML to be shown after logging in.